# Issue reading downloaded CSV

Tags: r, csv, https

I am trying to download a CSV from my database online and it appears to be working,

```
tempCSV <- postForm(myDB_URL, .params=myParameters)
```

but when I try to read the file,

```
> dat <- read.csv(textConnection(tempCSV))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in textConnection(tempCSV) : invalid 'text' argument
```

I've tried this too (don't laugh if I'm completely grabbing for straws here, it is 2:19am on a Friday night)

```
> dat <- read.csv(tempCSV)
```

with this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
'file' must be a character string or connection
```

For reference, this is what the data actually looks like:

```
> tempCSV[1:20]
 [1] 43 69 74 79 73 70 61 6e 20 43 6c 61 73 73 20 2d 20 46 69 6e
```

RStudio says it's raw[225758]

Here's what happens if I print the whole thing, if that helps at all:

```
> tempCSV
...
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 215758 entries ]
attr(,"Content-Type")

"application/x-comma-separated-values"
```

Comment: Seems like your `postForm` function is returning you a data object, not a csv file. You might want something like `writeChar(con="tempCSV.csv", postForm("https://orionsmind.quickbase.com/db/<mydb>act=API_GenResultsTable", ticket="<my ticket>", apptoken="<my token>", qid=<my saved query>, options="csv"))` to create a csv file in your working directory.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's going where.  You started with an R object, posted it via some URL, and then are "checking your work" by reading the resultant file back in?   If so,  can we start by verifying that a file "tempCSV" exists in your current working directory?

Comment: Thank you Carl.  I was trying to get, not post.  Conclusive proof I should just stop working at midnight :-/